# every solution $\vec{x}(t)$ of the equation$\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=(\epsilon L(t)+A)\vec{x}$ satisfies $\lim\limits_{t\to+\infty}\vec{x}(t)=\vec{0}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

**Question:**

Suppose $n\times n$ matrix function $L(t)$ is continuous and bounded on $\mathbb{R}$.

All eigenvalues of $n \times n$ matrix $A$ have negative real part.

Prove that:

There exists $\epsilon_0>0,$such that

$\forall0<\epsilon<\epsilon_0,$every solution $\vec{x}(t)$ of the equation$\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=(\epsilon L(t)+A)\vec{x}$ satisfies $\lim\limits_{t\to+\infty}\vec{x}(t)=\vec{0}$.

**Attempt:**

$\frac{d}{dt}||x||_2^2=\frac{d}{dt}x^Tx=x^T(\epsilon (L^T+L)+(A^T+A))x\leq \lambda_{max}\{\epsilon (L^T+L)+(A^T+A)\}||x||_2^2 $

Therefore,if we can show that $\lambda_{max}\{\epsilon (L^T+L)+(A^T+A)\}<0$,then $\lim\limits_{t\to+\infty} ||x(t)||=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Following the approach indicated by the OP, the required eigenvalue bounds follow from Weyl's inequality:

Let $M=N+R,\,N$ and $R$ be $ n \times n$ Hermitian matrices, with their respective eigenvalues $\mu_i,\,\nu_i,\,\rho_i$ in decreasing order as a function of $i$.
Then
$\nu_1 + \rho_n \le \mu_1 \le \nu_1 + \rho_1, \quad i=1,\dots,n.$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality

Comment: Thanks for your answer!But I'm wondering how to show that $\lambda_1(A^T+A)<0$,could you please give a hint?

Comment: It follows immediately from Weyl's inequality, because the eigenvalues of $L(t)$ are $O(\epsilon)$.